# C# convert ttf and otf to eot files

Tags: c#

Hi i trying to convert these files into eot format. I've found some c++ code for linux, that can do the job, but i need to do this on a windows server. But isn't there a .net implementation that can do the trick?

Hope someone can help me to find a solution

Answer (score -2):

Here is an online converter that is amazing! You can convert fonts to and from almost any format: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator
Hope it helps! :)